# Is it possible to compare two pages or iframe with selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, iframe, rspec, capybara

I have two web apps basically one client and one other admin. So as an admin I want to be able to let's say tweak the content page. Like change the color etc... and when I do that it should be reflected in the client side in some iframe. So I'd like to know if it is possible to compare the two contents with selenium(capybara,Rspec).

Comment: I hate to sound curt but the answer is yes.

Comment: Please make this question more specific, provide some code you have tried, and some sample HTML.

Comment: I just want to compare two pages and see if they contain the same css... I have no code yet I wanted to know if it's doable, thanks!